# Mysql processes on Ubuntu server

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, process, ram

When I check my process using htop on a relatively new install of Ubuntu on Linode, I see about 17 MySQL processes. None of them eat CPU, and each of them eats like 2.1% of ram.
My website isn't even running yet, I've not relocated the domain, I've just been setting up the server. Its like idle mode, and has all those processes and eats up all that ram. Is that normal?

Comment: using `htop` and to use `process` instead of `thread`. in addition, system software like database are likely to occupy RAM and CPU

Comment: Thanks, however I am using Nginx if i didnt mention, so it uses threads instead of processes afaik. I did some reading before setting it up, and most people suggest it instead of apache. You are saying that Nginx is not good? Or what else did you mean by using processes instead of threads? :) thanks

Comment: actuall you did not mentioned that. ok nginx is good at dealing with `php`, and apache is good at dealing with static file and request forward. in addition, mysql have multiple-thread, and nginx have multiple-process using php-fpm in parsing php. SO: what do you want to ask on earth?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `max_connections` within your mysql configuration. If your applications efficiently use/reuse connections, you probably need far fewer than 17.